# How to solve the traceback error, when it is not a code issue?

Tags: python, flask, command-line

So I downloaded this project (https://github.com/alectrocute/flasksaas) on my machine. Interesting is, that on my other computer everything works great, but not on this one. 
I am stuck at the point, where I want to initialize the database with following command:

```
$python manage.py initdb
```

I reinstalled python, the modules etc., but it doesn't help.
I checked my system environment variables in the settings (OS: Windows), everything seems fine.

Error which occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
__init__.py, line 6, in <module>
    app.config.from_object('app.config')
NameError: name 'config_dev' is not defined
```

Expected result: 
"SQL database has been created."

Comment: There's a symbolic link between config.py and config_dev.py. Did you run `make install && make dev` ?

Comment: `make install && make dev` does not work, because this command is for MacOS.

Comment: You need to use an equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the repo's [Makefile](https://github.com/alectrocute/flaskSaaS/blob/80c124cc3032bb739395ea75cbf168f4d8f6c456/Makefile), you'll find what each `make` target means:

> - `install` : run `$ pip install -r requirements.txt`
> - `dev` : copy (or link) the `config_dev.py` to `config.py`
> - `prod` : copy (or link) the `config_prod.py` to `config.py`